# JetBrains Goland - Possible to turn on "unused function or method call result" everywhere?

Tags: jetbrains-ide, goland

In the GoLand IDE the *unused function result* inspection highlights code where I forget to handle the return value. I want to be able to turn it on for all functions -- **is that possible**? One example where this saves me the most is with libs like *Shopspring Decimal*, where `num.Add(1)` returns the answer rather than adding one to the existing num.

I've tried regexes on either side below, but none seem to work. When adding functions from third-party libs it seems to work sometimes and but not others.

Settings > Editor > Inspections > Probable Bugs > Unused function or method call result

[image]

Comment: It's not possible at the moment. Feel free to request this feature on the issue tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/GO